# Blender "importer not included" error

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm trying to import a simple scene from blender in three.js. I'm following this tutorial for setting up the importer:

http://benchung.com/lesson-2-importing-model/

Now the issue is in step 3, right in front of the human figurine (inside the yellow rectangle) I'm getting an error sign that says "importer not included". I think I did everything right but Im getting this error. What am I doing wrong or missing to see this error

UPDATE: I also followed the three.js on github. For the new version of three.js the file name and structure has changed. But even now I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure when you are saying ' I also followed the three.js on github' if you are talking about three js lib or the blender exporter.
If you haven't already, download [this exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) and follow the steps. I did this 1 week ago and it works fine on Windows. Later when you export from blender to json format, don't forget to check the 'face materials' checkbox and uncheck the checkboxes in Scene

Comment: thanks for your response, in the link that you posted where it says "go to usage" and then there is a link that is suppose to look like the example given in windows. Where can I change that?

Comment: If you downloaded the exporter you should copy the 'io_three' folder and paste it here if you have windows 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.7X\scripts\addons'. Then in blender you go to File -> User Preferences -> Import Export -> And choose the file you saw in your tutorial